# Import module CairoPlot fails in Python

Tags: python, cairoplot

I'm using cairo plot to draw charts with python. I followed the instruction as stated on the website to install Cairplot, http://linil.wordpress.com/2008/09/16/cairoplot-11/ :

> ```
> sudo apt-get install bzr
> bzr branch lp:cairoplot/1.1
> ```

The installation completes successfully.
I then try to import the modules in python:

```
 >>> import CairoPlot Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>",
 line 1, in <module> ImportError: No
 module named CairoPlot
 >>> import cairo
 >>>
```

Importing cairo is fine, but I can't figure out why I am not able to import CairoPlot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bzr branch lp:cairoplot/1.1` creates a directory called `1.1` in your current working directory. Inside you'll find `CairoPlot.py`. Move `CairoPlot.py` into a directory which is listed in your `PYTHONPATH`, or edit your `PYTHONPATH` to include (the unfortunately named) `1.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Is the directory where CairoPlot is installed in your `$PYTHONPATH`? Do you need to run any setup scripts, like setuptools?

The repository appears to include a setup.py file, so you likely need to run setuptools to fully install the module.